# Review website and Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I'm rescripting a review website in which we review certain online services (for the sake of an example let's say antivirus subscriptions).

I'm struggling to find the right way to implement Schema.org markup for the single review pages.

Should I use the Schema.org `Product` type and nest my review details there?
Or is the `Product` type meant for webshops offering the product itself?

Or should I use the `Review` type and state the item as `itemReviewed`?

Comment: Related: [Google Structured Data: should I use the Review type or LocalBusiness type?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/109190/17633)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do this the Google-approved way, here is Google's example for a review:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Restaurant",
    "image": "http://www.example.com/seafood-restaurant.jpg",
    "name": "Legal Seafood",
    "servesCuisine": "Seafood",
    "telephone": "1234567",
    "address" :{
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "123 William St",
      "addressLocality": "New York",
      "addressRegion": "NY",
      "postalCode": "10038",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    }
  },
  "reviewRating": {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": "4"
  },
  "name": "A good seafood place.",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Bob Smith"
  },
  "reviewBody": "The seafood is great.",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Washington Times"
  }
}
</script>
```

Source: [Review Snippet - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet)

As you can see, they use the `itemReviewed` property to describe the item that they are reviewing. If you are reviewing an antivirus subscription, to borrow your example, you will probably want to use the `Service` type for your `itemReviewed`. If you want the structured data to really be complete for semantic web crawlers, make sure to fill in the `url` field with the service's official website, and the `sameAs` field with their Wikipedia and Wikidata pages, if they exist.

Comment: thank you for your response. The reviews sometimes contain 3000+ words. 
I'm debating if I should use CreativeWork fr the contents of the review and then only mark the review summary + rating as review part?